# Непонятная производительность запроса

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос, firebird

Есть таблица:

```
Id       English_word  Count_Repeat
3096     arranged           7
3240     arranged           4
3241     arranged           5
3087     almost             3
3252     arranged           6
4322     almost             2
```

Мне нужно:
1) сделать ‘*distinct*’ по полю ‘*English_word*’ (выбрать уникальные слова), но таким образом, чтобы в результате запроса, я имел два поля (*English_word*, *Count_Repeat*), т.е. результат запроса приносил **2** строки ("almost", "arranged"), в котором значение *Count_Repeat* роли не играет.
2) В полученном наборе данных, значения в поле *Count_Repeat* (всех строк выборки), *нужно уменьшить* на единицу (записав это значение в поле *Count_Repeat*).

Вот запрос:

```
update MAIN_TABLE set Count_Repeat = Count_Repeat-1 where ID in
(select ID from
 (select max(ID) as ID, English_word, Russian_word, max(Count_Repeat) as Count_Repeat from MAIN_TABLE
  where Count_Repeat > 0
group by English_word, Russian_word order by Count_Repeat))
```

который это делает.
В итоге у меня получается:
- первый (свеху) *select* выполняется - "Execute time = **0ms**", а
весь
- запрос (update) выполняется - "Execute time = **3s 812ms**" - обновить **2 записи.

это нормально?**

Answer (score 1):

У вас лишний подзапрос, сортировка по Count_Repeat не нужна. Попробуйте так:

```sql
update MAIN_TABLE set Count_Repeat = Count_Repeat-1
where id in (select max(id) 
             from MAIN_TABLE 
             where 
               Count_Repeat > 0 
             group by English_word, Russian_word);
```

Кроме того вы не рассказали сколько у вас данных и какие индексы есть. На первый взгляд может тормозить группировка по двум строковым полям, особенно если по ним нет индекса.

Comment: Немного не так, во-первых, мне нужно **получить выборку** *DataSet*, пункт 1) моего вопроса (поля *English_word*, *Count_Repeat*, для проведения на ними дальнейших операций), и только в полученных строках/значениях, вычитать единицу из *Count_Repeat*. А ваш запрос находит только максимальное *ID* с дальнейшем обновлением значений

Comment: @Konstantin78 ваш запрос никаких "дальнейших операций" не производит. Мой запрос - упрощение вашего. Речь в вопросе у вас о скорости была. Приводите полное описание задачи.

Comment: Да, извиняюсь, вы правы.

       Просто я не так выразился: у меня второй *select* (см. мой *вопрос*) в Delphi присвоен константе, которую я использую в Query -> SQL (для получения выборки (константа 1)). Когда я выполнил этот запрос. Я его подставляю в запрос по *Query -> Update* (константа 2). Т.о. константа1 = 'select max(ID) as ID,...', константа 2 = 'update MAIN_TABLE set Count_Repeat = Count_Repeat-1 where ID in (select ID from(%s)) and Count_Repeat > 0' - где %s - это константа1.   Решил не придумывать новый запрос - наверное - ЗРЯ